# MATLAB colorbar end tick issue

Tags: matlab, colorbar, contourf

In MATLAB2017a when I use contourf and then specify the colorbar ticks manually, the end tick is not shown.
The end tick corresponds to the largest value in the contour matrix.
Doing something like thins:

```
S = floor(rand(20)*20)+1;
maxS = max(max(S)); %S is an integer matrix obtained from the previous code
tickStep = maxS/10;
contourf(S, 30)
bar = colorbar('XTick', [1,tickStep:tickStep:maxS]);
```

Is it a bug or is it a "feature"?
How I can work around it?

Comment: Please provide code that can reproduce the problem you're seeing (see [mcve]). In your case, you should include some part (or all) of `S` which still causes an issue. Please also mention the MATLAB version you're using. Lastly, you might be able solve it by setting `CLim` to `CLim +[-1,1].*eps(CLim)`.

Comment: Fixed. Basically this issue should arise with almost any `S` composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself:

Basically it is related to the way `contourf(S,30)` works. If we plot the values of the lines with `contourf(S,30,'ShowText','on')` the highest value will be lower than `maxS`. So the last tick is out of the range of possible values of the contour plot.

The best solution I came up with is to use `contourf(S,linspace(1,maxS,30))`.Now the end tick is visible.